# Linux Mint Cinamon: Keyboard shortcut for a specific keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

In KDE I used to use

- Ctrl+1 for English
- Ctrl+2 for second language
- Ctrl+3 for third language

This is very convenient because Windows 10 also allows you to use these keyboard shortcuts to switch keyboard layouts.
As a result, it doesn't matter what OS I use - the keyabord layouts switches the same way.
And one key shortcut for certain language.

But how to use the same approach in Linux Mint Cinnamon?